# dapper left join & mapping query

Tags: .net-core, dapper

There is one-to-many relation between Brand and Campaign entities,

With given Id I need to select Campaign and related Brand entity along with it.
TO do so:

```
     public async Task<Campaign> GetAsync(int id)
        {
            using var dbConnection = _context.CreateConnection();
            string query = @"SELECT c.[Id], c.[BrandId], c.[StartDate], 
            c.[EndDate],b.[Id] FROM [dbo].[Campaign] c
                            left join [dbo].[Brand] b on c.[BrandId] = b.[Id]
                            WHERE c.[Id] = @Id";
            var campaign = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Campaign, Brand, Campaign>(query, (campaign, brand) =>
            {
                campaign.Brand = brand;

                return campaign;
            }, splitOn: "BrandId", param: new { Id = id });
            return campaign.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

code above not throws exception but child brand entity is not correct.(its dummy record, and BrandId is 0 whereas its valu is 5 in database)

whats missing here?

entity def:

```
   public class Campaign : SqlEntityBase
    {
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    }

 public class Brand : SqlEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Campaign> Campaign { get; set; } = new List<Campaign>();
    }
```

Comment: You aren't selecting any `Brand` columns so it's no wonder `Brand` is empty.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos edited query with b.[Id] but still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query doesn't make sense. You're splitting on `BrandId` in dapper but you never select anything to do with the brand in the query. With your current code, dapper is parsing the SQL column `Id` into your `Campaign` POCO (which it cant do because there isn't a property called Id nor have you anything mapped to it in the campaign class).

And then it see's `BrandId` and then parses everything after that into the `Brand` POCO, but your remaining columns that you're selecting are the start and end dates for the campaign.

In summary: You need to include the Brand data into the SQL query. You're joining onto the table, but only selecting the campaign data.

Comment: "include Brand data into sql" well I have edited post for it, but still same?

Comment: Again, like I mentioned, you also have to understand what Dapper does with the data and what `SplitOn` does. You have told dapper that your data is in the following order `<Brand, Campaign>` and youre splitting on `BrandId` meaning, the first columns up to `BrandId` will be parsed into the `Brand` class, and the following columns will be parsed into the `Campaign` class. Take another look at your query.

Comment: now I understood, and it fixed thanks.